# Invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to solve for $X$ :

$$AX+AXB=7C \  \Rightarrow \ AX[I+B]=5C \\ \text{ we suppose that the matrix } A \text{ is invertible } \\ \Rightarrow A^{-1}AX[I+B]=A^{-1}5C \  \Rightarrow X[I+B]=A^{-1}5C  \\  \text{ we suppose that the matrix } [I+B] \text{ is invertible} \\ \Rightarrow X[I+B][I+B]^{-1}=A^{-1}5C[I+B]^{-1}  \ \Rightarrow \ X=A^{-1}5C[I+B]^{-1}$$

$$$$

Do we have that $A^{-1}5C[I+B]^{-1}=5A^{-1}C[I+B]^{-1}$ ?

So that $[I+B]$ is invertible does $B$ have to be invertible? 
$$$$

---

**EDIT:**

We have that $X$ and $A$ are invertible and that $A$ is symmetric, so $A=A^T$.

I want to solve for $X$ at the equations $A(X+B)^T=(XC)^T $ and $X(I+AX)=((A-I)X^T)^T$.

I have done the following:

$$A(X+B)^T=(XC)^T \ \Rightarrow (A(X+B)^T)^T=((XC)^T)^T \\ \Rightarrow ((X+B)^T)^TA^T=XC \ \Rightarrow (X+B)A=XC \\ \Rightarrow (X+B)AA^{-1}=XCA^{-1} \ \Rightarrow X+B=XCA^{-1} \\ \Rightarrow XCA^{-1}-X=B \ \Rightarrow X(CA^{-1}-I)=B \\ \Rightarrow X=B(CA^{-1}-I)^{-1}$$
So that we can solve for $X$ we have to assume that the matrix $(CA^{-1}-I)$ is invertible.

$$X(I+AX)=((A-I)X^T)^T \ \Rightarrow X(I+AX)=(X^T)^T(A-I)^T \\ \Rightarrow X(I+AX)=X(A-I)^T \ \Rightarrow X^{-1}X(I+AX)=X^{-1}X(A-I)^T \\ \Rightarrow I+AX=(A-I)^T \ \Rightarrow AX=(A-I)^T-I \\ \Rightarrow A^{-1}AX=A^{-1}((A-I)^T-I) \\ \Rightarrow X=A^{-1}((A-I)^T-I)$$

Is everything correct?

Comment: Yes, the scalar can be put at the beginning. No,  B must not be invertible.

Comment: I see... Thank you!! :-) @callculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, the equality hold, since $5$ is a scalar.

For the second question, take $I+B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

$B$ is not invertible, but $I+B$ is.

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: Could you take a look also at the edit part of my original question? Is everything correct? Could I improve something?

Comment: I cannot spot anything wrong. But a small thing, in the second one, when you take X off, by multiplying by the inverse. You have assumed that X is invertible. However, I think it is possible to have more solutions, when X is not invertible. So,I think it is not that easy after all.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you have assumed X to be invertible. I think everything is fine with the new part

Comment: Ok... Thank you!! :-)